# Do you have to worry about php function security?

Tags: php, security, class, function

I am creating a site that uses classes with functions to modify information in the database, and to also give information to users, but when users login they have access to the same class and all functions - including ones I don't want them to be able to use. Is there some sort of security problem here?

My thinking is that there wouldn't be since the PHP is interpreted before it even gets to the browser and user, so the only way they would have access to an unauthorized function is if they got access to a page that uses it - but I could protect those pages in another manner to prevent that.

Is my thinking correct, or am I completely off?

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of this: Are there any way a user can invoke one of your functions in a way you don't intend? (Examples could be visiting a certain link, clicking a button or other user interface stuff.)

As you have said, PHP is interpreted on the server. A user can't invoke / touch your source code unless you make it possible.

Important: **Even though users can't see the user interface for something doesn't mean it's secure.**

If visiting a certain link or submitting a certain form will execute a certain function, **hiding the link or form won't solve your problem**. A user **can still** enter the link in their browser, or forge a POST request that executes the action.

You can solve this problem by checking if the current user has privileges to execute a certain action at runtime.

Examples:

```
if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
    doSomething();
}

if ($user->isAdmin()) {
    doSomething();
}

if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin') {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: @arex1337: The functions are called through scripts, which are called with buttons and what not like you said, but I would have two completely separate interfaces for customers and admins - so customers won't have access to the admin interface which uses the functions I don't want customers having access to. I just wanted to make sure my thinking was correct before I continued developing.

Comment: In response to your edit - wouldn't using a security check on every page and script that uses the functions prevent exactly that problem? If they don't pass the check - I could just kill the script with die() or exit(). Edit: The admin interface would have this check implemented.

Comment: @Key Yes, if you are able block off access to a whole page that is certainly acceptable. However, if security "per page" is not enough you need to do it "per action".

Comment: @Key What you are doing is essentially what I'm saying you should do. Only you have put the whole page inside doSomething() - which is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Key - If you aren't already, seriously consider using a proven framework such as CakePHP, Symfony, ExpressionEngine/CodeIgniter (perhaps the easiest to understand), or some other one. Do not attempt to roll your own solution if you're struggling to understand the security risks inherent in web development.

Comment: @arex1337 What I have done in the past is put a function at the top of each page like: if(!grantAccess()): die("No Access"); endif; (grantAccess() would return true or false based on certain factors.) Would that not be acceptable, or is that okay? If there is a security hole with that - what would it be?

Comment: @Key Yes, that is secure. Assuming the user can't manipulate the factors being considered inside grantAccess().

Comment: @Key - For instance, review Chapter 6: Inside the Controller Layer of this PDF http://www.symfony-project.org/get/pdf/gentle-introduction-1.4-en.pdf

Comment: @arex1337 Can you manipulate session data that is stored in session variables? That is the only way I have used. For example, I would store the user's permission group (taken from a database table) in a session variable and then use that to check for access permission. Would it be more secure to not use the session and specifically ask the database for the permission group every time I want to check it?

Comment: @Key No, getting permissions from the database once and storing them in $_SESSION is perfectly secure. I do it basically the same way.

Comment: Okay - just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

How are your functions called?

If users can not access functions you do not want them to, you are almost there.

Just make sure that they cannot edit any variable in an unintended way...

Comment: My functions are called through scripts that are accessed through forms and links etc.

Comment: Will changing anything in the URI execute any function? Or do an unwanted edit to how a function acts?

Comment: I would secure the script by checking if a user has access to it - so I don't think there would be a way to do it even having physical access to the page (without authorization access to the page)